What is considered as cheating in Egg Surprise?
I just started playing Egg Surprise and they just released a new update with regards to Anti-cheat and the release notes state:

The following features have been added: Anti-cheat and fair play protection tools

But it doesn't actually state what is considered cheating, and what are the consequences of cheating?
Are using Auto Clickers considered cheating?
Can anyone shine some light on what this Anti-cheat update actually brings and does?
